# On flask application - the URI start with a question mark and it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, amazon-eks

### This is the request that I'm trying to make it work: (return 200 OK)

> `curl --cacert cert.pem -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @./request.json https://localhost:8443/?timeout=30s`

The problem with this request is the question mark at the beginning of the URI.
If I will write without it, like this:
https://localhost:8443/timeout=30s **It will work well**.

This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import logging
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/<path:str>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index(str):
    content = request.get_json()
    response = {
        "apiVersion": "admission.k8s.io/v1",
        "kind": "AdmissionReview",
        "response": {
            "uid": content["request"]["uid"],
            "allowed": True
        }}
    return response
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cert_path = "/home/docker"
    app.run(ssl_context=(os.path.join(cert_path, 'cert.pem'), os.path.join(cert_path, 'key.pem')), debug=True, port=8443, host="0.0.0.0")
```

### ***for now, the request is returning:***

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@app.route('/<path:str>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

will not match with

```
https://localhost:8443/?timeout=30s
```

Your route would need to look something like

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```